# How to delete Data after ten hours if user do not have an Account?

Tags: django

```
class Data(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    other = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

How to delete `Data` after ten hours of added if user do not have an `Account`

Answer (score 1):

I used something like this in the past. I would add a "created" field on the Model Data:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    other = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I would set a [cron-job](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/), that verifies for Data created without a user association in the last 10 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

on your model Data, and check it hourly on a cronjob when its past 10 hours of it's creation, in case user is None, delete.

And call them, like in:

```
delete_time = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
to_delete = Data.objects.filter(created__lt=delete_time, user=None).delete()
```

:)

Comment: You recommend using django-cron app?

Comment: I think it's not very important what cron tool you use, but any cron job would do the job, find one that suits you best.

Comment: Ok, thanks but if user has data in the Data model and Account model everything is ok but if user do not have data in Account and only in Data model - all data from Data models must be removed